# Ethereum wallets that support "Custom RPC URL" like Metamask

Tags: wallets, metamask, rpc

I'm running a private blockchain and I've been using Metamask connected to my custom RPC URL with no issues.. I'm curious if there's any other Ethereum wallet that let's you add and connect to a custom RPC URL.

Answer (score 1):

[MyCrypto.com](https://mycrypto.com) and their desktop application do (https://download.mycrypto.com)

Comment: Thanks! I just saw that MyEtherWallet and Mist let you connect too: https://bitfalls.com/2018/03/26/connecting-myetherwallet-mist-metamask-private-blockchain/